# Why size to fit doesn't work at all and do nothing in this obvious scenario

Tags: objective-c, subviews, superview

Let's examine this line of codes (only 1 actually change anything)

```
PO(self.containerForFormerHeader);
PO(self.containerForFormerHeader.subviews);
[self.containerForFormerHeader sizeToFit];
PO(self.containerForFormerHeader);
```

Result:

```
self.containerForFormerHeader: <UIView: 0x8b669c0; frame = (0 75; 320 0); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b5eb30>>
self.containerForFormerHeader.subviews: (
    "<UIImageView: 0xd572210; frame = (0 0; 320 10); autoresize = LM+RM+TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd572250>> - shading-top-Table.png"
)
self.containerForFormerHeader: <UIView: 0x8b669c0; frame = (0 75; 320 0); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b5eb30>>
```

From the result it's obvious that:

1. The view has a height of 0.
2. The view has a subview whose height is 10
3. After sizetofit, nothing change. How come?

I can compute the frame directly however, this bothers me.

Comment: can you explain more as to what you are doing & maybe post some code?

Comment: If the subview and the superview are the exact same size, what is the point of having a superview (besides making the graphics hardware work a little harder to comply with your request to layer an extraneous view onto the window)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the `sizeToFit` method on a view, it ends up calling the `sizeThatFits:` method on the view. The default implementation of `sizeThatFits:` returns the view's current size.

So unless your custom view explicitly overrides the `sizeThatFits:` method to return an appropriate size to contain its subviews, nothing will change size when you call `sizeToFit`.

This is all spelled out in the docs for `UIView sizeToFit` and `UIView sizeThatFits:`.

Classes like UILabel do implement `sizeThatFits:` to return an appropriate size.

Comment: It's a duplicate question actually. Thanks.